# track gps position and time(zone) to file

Tags: android, gps, gps-tracking, timezones

Do you know any app for Android that can track phone's position and UTC+local time to file? Preferably it should have no external connectivity (but acceptable), use some simple (or standard) format and be aware that during movement current timezone can change (critical). If it was optimized for battery usage it would be great (eg. during night when there is no movement there is probably no need to turn on GPS).

Comment: Some apps in [my corresponding listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking) should meet your needs. As I've never needed such myself, I cannot give any clear recommendation. An app that I use is [Tower Collector](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/info.zamojski.soft.towercollector/), which allows you to save your track as GPX as a side-feature. Its main feature is to feed the OpenCellID database for "offline location", so you could serve a good purpose at the same time :)

Comment: Do you know if any of these apps can track timezone changes? I would need that to be able to order photos made with cell phone and those made with camera on a timeline.

Comment: I'm not aware of *tracking* time zone. But wouldn't the timestamps include the timezone? I at least remember something like that from the photos of my last vacation (I could see the "local time" as well as the relation to "my local time" – I just don't remember where was which; most likely the photos timestamp was "vacation time" while Exif data had another).

Comment: I would also expect it to be so. But while on one phone TZ data can be extracted, the other one (I think Huawei P9) uses local time for phone information.

Comment: In the above comment I meant not "phone information", but "photo information".

Comment: @Izzy I like the idea of helping out Tower Collector, but when I try to install it via F-Droid the .APK link is broken :-(  I guess I will have to contact the author

Comment: @Mawg Uh? I've installed it from there. Do you use the F-Droid app on Android, or did you try to manually download the TC APK? I just tried the latter and it came down all right. Maybe network issues on your end? If you're using the app, I'd suggest to perform an index refresh and try again.

Comment: I just tried again with the F-Droid app (as I did yesterday) & it's fine :-)